# Like functionality in Django

Tags: python, django, models

I'm developing a social platform and currently coding the like functionality for user posts. However, I can't seem to make it work. These are my Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    picturefile = models.ImageField(upload_to="post_content", blank=True)

class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True)
```

I pass the post ID through my url as 'post_id', and then in my views:

```
def liking(request, post_id):
    newlike = Like.objects.create()
    newlike.post = post_id
    newlike.user = request.user
    newlike.save()
    return redirect(reverse('dashboard'))
```

However, it returns the following error:

```
Cannot assign "'47'": "Like.post" must be a "Post" instance.
```

Does anyone knows what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `newlike.post` a number (integer field) while it is expecting a `Post` instance.

This sould work:

```
from django.http.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def liking(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
    newlike = Like.objects.create(user=request.user, post=post)
    return redirect(reverse('dashboard'))
```

Note 1: Better use the handy shortcut [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) in order to raise a 404 error when the specific Post does not exist.
Note 2: By calling `objects.create` will automatically save into the db and return an instance!

Comment: Why does my 'post' in the Like model return a username? instead of the content?

Comment: You mean like `print newlike.post` returns the username? This is actually defined inside the `Post` model with the `__unicode__()` (if you use python 2) or the `__str__()` (for python 3) method. This method should return the actual string representation when you do a `print` on that object.

Comment: No, I mean the model object itself (so: post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True)). When I go to the database, I wanna see who (in this case the user object) liked which post (the post object).  The user object correctly returns who's username, but the post object also returns an username; the username from the post owner, instead of the post's content itself.

Comment: The database stores `ForeignKey`s (aka ids, integer fields) in order to do the appropriate relationships. To check which user liked a specific post jsut do a: `Like.objects.filter(user__username='the_username_here').values('post__content')`.

Comment: Thank you! You're helping me out great. How do I display how many likes a post has in my template?

Comment: `Like.objects.filter(post=post_id_here).count()`. But in order to better understand how querysets work you should read the [queryset API docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/). Its an excellent source of knowledge!

Comment: Note that you don't actually NEED to fetch the `Post` instance - you could just assign the `post_id` to `like.post_id` (or pass it as `post_id` named param to `create()`

Comment: You are right, its not required. Its actual an extra db query. But I think he/she will figure it out in the future...

Answer (score 1):

newlike.post should be a Post object, not an int.

You need to find post by id first:

```
post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
newlike.post = post
```

or, if you don't want to do this lookup:

```
newlike.post_id = post_id
```

Comment: Why does my 'post' in the Like model return a username? instead of the content?